# What is the difference between GWT, play, vaadin, grails, wicket, vert.x?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, frameworks

May I know what is the difference between:-

1)GWT
2)play
3)vaadin
4)grails
5)wicket
6)vert.x

Are these technologies/framework? Also these which layer exactly covered like presentation, persistence layer, etc.

Eg:-

Hibernate- Hibernate is an object-relational mapping tool, a persistence framework.

JSF - JavaServer Faces is component-based presentation framework.

Struts - Struts is an action-based presentation framework.

Struts2 - Struts 2 is an action-based presentation framework, the version 2 of the above (created from a merge of WebWork with Struts).

Spring - Spring is an application framework and inversion of control container.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Play - Is a framework you can use it for backend work. I think Play is best choice for smaller Projects. For bigger you can use Spring.  But maybe its a religion Play vs Spring.

Vaadin is like GWT ( as i know Vaadin was build on top on GWT) is a framework for Webapplications Frontend. You can use it in a combination with play or spring. As I know Spring STS IDE supports Vaadin little little better thatn Play.

Withj 4, 5 and 6 i never worked